# When starting a new Activity for video player, how to force android video player to not exit after the video is played

Tags: java, android, video, android-intent, android-activity

I am using the following intent to play a video with the android default Video Player.

```
        File file = new File(galleryList.get(getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()).getPath());
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        if (GalleryMediaHelper.isVideoFile(galleryList.get(getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()).getPath())) {
            i.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, AUTHORITY, file), "video/*");
        }
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        if (i.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null)
            context.startActivity(i);
```

So far so good. The video player starts playing the video.
The problem is that, when the video is played the video player is closed and the user returns to the my app. -> NOK

How can I force video player to not close and either play on repeat the video or just wait for user to press back to exit video player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that, when the video is played the video player is closed and the user returns to the my app

That behavior will depend on the video player app. There are hundreds, if not thousands, of possible video player apps that might handle your `Intent`, based on pre-installed and user-installed video player apps.

> How can I force video player to not close and either play on repeat the video or just wait for user to press back so that he can do whatever he/she wants with the video player (pause, stop, replay etc)?

That is not possible. The behavior of a video player app is up to the developers of that app.

If you need that level of control over the user experience, implement your own video player, such as by integrating ExoPlayer.

Comment: When using video player to normally play videos, it has an option in settings to `repeat video playback` that is selectable. However, when opening settings from the spawned activity of the same video player when playing a video from my app, the setting for `repeat video playback` is grayed out. Too bad :|

Comment: @RandomType: That is the behavior of that specific video player app. You might improve your results incrementally by using a real MIME type, not `video/*`. However, overall, you are delegating video playback to an arbitrary app, and what that app does is not completely under your control.

Comment: I have tried `/video/mp4` but its the same!

Comment: I was trying to find maybe a more specific `Intent.ACTION_XXX` than `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` too or a `Intent.FLAG_XXXXX" but didnt find anything.

Comment: I think its only doable with VLC, there are arguments to pass for repeat mode. Well that would do for me but If there is no VLC then no can do...

https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC-0-9-x_command-line_help/

Comment: @RandomType: Yes, some players may offer `Intent` extras that you can pass. Not all players will support those extras.

Comment: Btw is there a way to set arguments for VLC when setting the intent to play the video?

Comment: @RandomType: I have no idea. But VLC is open source, so you can probably find out.